# Release Management 2013 with TFS 2015

Tags: ms-release-management, tfs-2015

Trying do decide if I need to upgrade our entire environment or one piece at a time.  Does anyone know if Microsoft Release Management 2013 works with TFS 2015?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say it works with TFS 2015 based on this https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/features/release-mgmt-licensing-vs.aspx

> Release Management Requirements
>
> Software and licensing requirements for Release Management
>
> Different pieces of software work together across multiple computers
>   to enable Release Management for Visual Studio 2013 and Visual Studio
>   2015.
>
> 1. Release Management Client for Visual Studio 2013 or Visual Studio
>      2015 – for creating, updating, or deleting a release pipeline
>      sequence. This software is included in the following MSDN
>      subscription levels: Visual Studio Enterprise with MSDN, Visual
>      Studio Test Professional with MSDN, MSDN Platforms.
> 2. Release
>      Management Server for Team Foundation Server 2013 or Team Foundation
>      Server 2015. This software is included with Team Foundation Server
>      and is installed on the same server.
> 3. Team Foundation Server 2013 or
>      Team Foundation Server 2015
> 4. Microsoft Deployment Agent (optional) –
>      for machines receiving deployments from Release Management. As of
>      January 1, 2015, no license is required for a machine to receive
>      deployments.

Comment: Thank you for doing the research:)